# Using helm to deploy htpasswd secret

Tags: nginx

I want to deploy nginx with basic auth via: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

I'm in the process of using helm to generate a htpasswd hash, I want to use the following template function `htpasswd`: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#cryptographic-and-security-functions

My template is as follow:

```
{{- $passwd := (htpasswd "foo" "bar") -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: htpasswd
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
stringData:
    htpasswd: {{ $passwd }}
```

However when I try to authenticate via nginx i get the following error:

```
*13 crypt_r() failed (22: Invalid argument)
```

Does this mean nginx doesn't support bcrypt hash password?  Is there a way around this so I can still use helm templates.  Can i provide a custom htpasswd function?

Answer (score 4):

Nginx does not have an internal implementation of the bcrypt algorithm. Actually, the only one algorithm implemented by nginx itself is the apache `apr1` MD5 version (read [this](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/382) nginx trac ticket), for everything else it relies on a system `libc` library [`crypt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) implementation. Only a few Linux distributions shipped with the tweaked `glibc` version that has bcrypt support; [Alpine Linux](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) is one of the examples. You can check [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/29) issue of `docker-nginx` image, especially [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/29#issuecomment-194817391) comment, or [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3150) one of the `ingress-nginx`.

Unfortunately I don't have an answer is there a way to provide a custom crypt function using helm. I think helm developers should consider to add at least SHA-256/SHA-512 hashing functions. Too sad there is so many software thinking the world of web servers is limited to apache.

**TL;DR**

The default POSIX `crypt` function implementation uses a 56 bit DES, which is definitely too week nowadays and not something anybody should rely on. However GNU `glibc` library [implements](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html#:%7E:text=Availability%20in%20glibc) some extensions:

> The glibc version of this function supports additional encryption algorithms.
>
> If `salt` is a character string starting with the characters `$id$` followed by a string optionally terminated by `$`, then the result has the form:
>
> ```
> $id$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> `id` identifies the encryption method used instead of DES and this then determines how the rest of the password string is interpreted. The following values of `id` are supported:
>
> | ID | Method |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | MD5 |
> | 2a | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux distributions) |
> | 5 | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7) |
> | 6 | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7) |
>
> Thus, `$5$salt$encrypted` and `$6$salt$encrypted` contain the password encrypted with, respectively, functions based on SHA-256 and SHA-512.
>
> `salt` stands for the up to 16 characters following `$id$` in the salt. The `encrypted` part of the password string is the actual computed password. The size of this string is fixed:
>
> | Hash function | Length |
> | --- | --- |
> | MD5 | 22 characters |
> | SHA-256 | 43 characters |
> | SHA-512 | 86 characters |
>
> The characters in `salt` and `encrypted` are drawn from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`.  In the MD5 and SHA implementations the entire `key` is significant (instead of only the first 8 bytes in DES).
>
> Since glibc 2.7, the SHA-256 and SHA-512 implementations support a user-supplied number of hashing rounds, defaulting to 5000. If the `$id$` characters in the salt are followed by `rounds=xxx$`, where `xxx` is an integer, then the result has the form
>
> ```
> $id$rounds=yyy$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> where `yyy` is the number of hashing rounds actually used. The number of rounds actually used is 1000 if `xxx` is less than 1000, 999999999 if `xxx` is greater than 999999999, and is equal to `xxx` otherwise.

So, why the `glibc` doesn't have a Blowfish (bcrypt) support by default? There is a [long read](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1519843) from Red Hat. In short, bcrypt considered to have no benefits over SHA-256 or SHA-512 functions using enough hashing rounds. I'm not a cryptographic expert, nevertheless the article seems reasonable to me. For my own purposes, to not be stucked with the weak apache MD5 1000 hashing rounds algorithm, I wrote a script that I'm using to generate passwords based on the SHA-512 default (5000) hashing rounds function, maybe someone will find it useful:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, random, string;
from getpass import getpass;
from crypt import crypt;
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1];
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        password = sys.argv[2];
    else:
        password = getpass('Enter password: ');
        confirm = getpass('Re-enter password: ');
        if password != confirm:
            sys.stderr.write('Passwords mismatch!\n');
            exit(1);
    random.seed();
    salt = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + './', 8));
    print('%s:%s' % (username, crypt(password, '$6$%s$' % salt)));
else:
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: htpasswd.py <username> [<password>]\n');
```

This one was written to be used on a CentOS 7 (shipped with Python 2.7) and may or may not require some modifications to be used with Python 3. It can be easily tweaked to use more hashing rounds replacing `$6$%s$` with lets say `$6$rounds=10000$%s$` (to use 10000 hashing rounds instead) and so on.